# get_the_foo() in the loop - does it perform another query?

Tags: loop, query, performance

I'm unclear on the `get_the_foo()` style of functions, for example `get_the_permalink()`.

My main question is: when this is performed in The Loop, is another SQL query executed (besides the original `WP_Query()`)?

But: if performed by itself, e.g. `get_the_permalink($someId)`, a query *is* executed, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query results for posts, terms, and metadata get placed in cache. If a function is called that accesses data from previously queried objects within the same request (or you're using a persistent cache mechanism that maintains data across requests), it will not trigger another query and will instead fetch the data from cache.

Comment: Looking at the `get_instance()` function in my answer, `wp_cache_get()` tries to look for the `$post_id` in a group called `posts`. Does this also include secondary queries or *only* the main `wp_query` posts?

Comment: This answer seems to be confirmed after tests with query logging (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql) using `select count(*) from mysql.general_log where argument like "%wp_%" and event_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 SECOND and command_type="Query"`.  The query count does not increase after a page refresh when using `get_the_title()` vs. a test string, which indicates the cache is alive and well.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like <s>yes</s> *it depends* whether it does create a new query or not. As Milo has pointed out in his answer, WordPress using a caching system. The function stack looks like this:

[`get_the_permlink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) calls [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) calls [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) which when given a post ID does this:

[`$_post = WP_Post::get_instance( $post );`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L641) which looks like:

```
/**
 * Retrieve WP_Post instance.
 *
 * @static
 * @access public
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID.
 * @return WP_Post|bool Post object, false otherwise.
 */
public static function get_instance( $post_id ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $post_id = (int) $post_id;
        if ( ! $post_id )
                return false;
        $_post = wp_cache_get( $post_id, 'posts' );
        if ( ! $_post ) {
                $_post = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d LIMIT 1", $post_id ) );
                if ( ! $_post )
                        return false;
                $_post = sanitize_post( $_post, 'raw' );
                wp_cache_add( $_post->ID, $_post, 'posts' );
        } elseif ( empty( $_post->filter ) ) {
                $_post = sanitize_post( $_post, 'raw' );
        }
        return new WP_Post( $_post );
}
```

In this `get_instance()` function it checks whether it can find the `$post_id` in the `posts` cache, if it does then it **does not** need to actually query the database. I'm not sure if this counts for secondary queries or main queries though.

Sometimes you can get around some of the `get_{$field}()` functions by accessing the object itself but I don't think you'll ever see a huge performance difference by using them. MYSQL is pretty fast and powerful so I wouldn't consider them a bad thing or something to stay away from.

Comment: Thanks @Howdy!  I have to say though this is not very good for performance - at even low levels of traffic, hitting the database multiple times unnecessarily will cause trouble immediately...perhaps I'll just access the post object properties instead.

Comment: the important part you're overlooking is the line `$_post = wp_cache_get( $post_id, 'posts' );`, all query results get placed in cache, so if it was already queried within the same request (or you're using a persistent cache mechanism) it *will not* trigger another query.

Comment: @Milo I'm not familiar with WordPress caching, maybe if you get a moment you could post an explanation as an answer? This question also piques my curiosity.

Comment: @Milo - ahh, thanks.  I just turned on logging in my DB and there are a ridiculous amount of requests being made (20+ on the 2015 theme home page, unmodified). Still investigating my original question using loggin now.

Comment: @Steve if you're having page speed problems ( just an assumption ), may I ask how many plugins you currently have installed? 20+ queries is not unusual.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - no page speed problems, plugins "Featured Image" and "Subtitles" (but these aren't used in the vanilla 2015 theme).  20+ is for the unmodified version - if I put Ajax into that, or use the `get_the_foo()` methods, this number jumps up alarmingly quickly...and seems to smell.

Comment: So after testing with logging, it seems that another query is not made if there's results in the cache. See my comment on @Milo's answer.